# Issue with changing Q library version from 0.9.6 to 0.9.7

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

I was working with **q** library for a short period of time, and 
had success with processing data that I get from ajax in sequential manner.

By sequential processing of data I mean that after each of ajax call, I do a set of **.then(** function(){} **)** and continue onto the next ajax call ...

As part of processing a single data entry (ajax data) I have to output result of ajax on screen.
I have a deferred object that I resolve after I enter text from ajax data into a div - I am notifying ( with Q's *progressHandler* ) that I am done with entering text into a div (100% of text was entered into a div).

Everything works as expected in q's v. 0.9.6.
But with v. 0.9.7 for some reason I get a TypeError {} :s 
Apparently the deferred object does not propagate the progress and fails for some reason.
The changelog did not help me much: [**q changelog**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

I have prepared 2 versions of code, simplified it as much as I can.
Here is version that works - [**0.9.6**](http://jsfiddle.net/gogromat/MMXmr/) and the one that does not work - [**0.9.7**](http://jsfiddle.net/gogromat/ZTvkM/).
Both examples have **same code**, the only difference is the version of q library.

I have an explanation of the code in the CSS section.
I hope that I am being as clear as possible there.

I apologize in advance if this is some stupid question.

---

And since I can't just post JSFiddle links, here is the code:

**Libraries** that I use:

- jQuery
- ajaxFake by ANas Nakawa
- Teletype (me - for typing text into a div)
- yodaProgress (me - a graphical progress bar. Has .progress(step 0.00 - 1.00) and .isDone() functions)
- q v. 0.9.6 / q v. 0.9.7

**Html**:

`<div id="progress_1"></div>`

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // For DEFERRED object (referencing in 2.2.1)
    var mainObject = {
    }

    // For fake ajax Data
    $.ajax.fake.registerWebservice('blah', function (data) {
        return {
            result: 'My fake ajax result should be typed into the div!', 
        };
    });

    // 1. START
    var nextTick = Q.when();

    // 2. PROCESS 3 ITEMS SEQUENTIALLY
    for (var i = 0, length = 3; i < length; i ++) {
        nextTick = nextTick.then(
            processAjaxCall,
            function(error)     { console.log("This is an error 2.");   },
            function(progress)  { console.log("This is a progress 2."); }
        );

    }

    // 3. FINALLY DO THIS
    nextTick.fin(
        function(result)    { console.log("This is a final result 3.");     },
        function(error)     { console.log("This is an error 3.");   },
        function(progress)  { console.log("This is a progress 3.");}
    );


    // 2.0   ONE OF 3 SEQUENTIALL ITEMS
    function processAjaxCall () {

        var fakeResult;

        // 2.1.   AN AJAX DATA
        var promise = Q.when(
            fakeAjax()
        );

        // 2.2.   SETTING OF TEXT (from 2.1.) INTO DIV
        var promiseToDo = promise.then(
            function (result) {
                console.log("Result of ajax call:", result);
                return setText(result);
            },
            function (error)    { console.log("Ajax call error 2.2:", error);       },
            function (progress) { console.log("Ajax call progress 2.2:", progress); }
        );

        // 2.3. SETTING OF PROGRESS (100% - color green for a DIV)
        return promiseToDo.then(
            function (result) {
                console.log("Text was set 2.3");
            }, 
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error 2.3:", error);
            }, 
            function (progress) {

                var promiseElement = new YodaProgress(

                    $("#progress_1")

                    ,{
                        doneCSSRule: {
                            'background-color': "#00CC00"
                        }
                    }
                );

                promiseElement.progress(parseFloat(progress).toFixed(2));

                if (promiseElement.isDone()) {
                    mainObject.deferred.resolve();
                }

                //console.log("2.3 Progress %:", progress);
            }
        );

    }


    // 2.1.1 - a fake Ajax Data
    // Anas Nakawa
    // https://github.com/anasnakawa/jquery.ajax.fake
    function fakeAjax () {
        return $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'jsonp',
            fake: true,
            url:'blah'
        });
    }

    // 2.2.1 - setting text into a DIV
    function setText (result) {

        console.log('Passing in result:', result);
        console.log('About to set text to:', result.result);

        mainObject.deferred = Q.defer();
        promise = mainObject.deferred.promise.when(

            // Teletype is a library to type text into a DOM element
            // as if human was typing, sorta
            Teletype(
                document.getElementById("progress_1"), 
                result.result, 
                40, 
                true, 
                function (i, l) {

                    mainObject.deferred.notify(
                        parseFloat((i+1)/l).toFixed(2)
                    );
                }
            )
            //,function(error)      { console.log("This is an error 2.2.1", error);       }
            //,function(progress)   { console.log("This is a progress 2.2.1", progress);}
        );
        console.log("RETURNING PROMISE");
        return promise;
    }


});
```

**Explanation**:

```
  If it is v. 0.9.7 I GET a "TypeError {}" and div is typed in differently
  If it is v. 0.9.6 it works as expected.

  Code Explanation:

  Forget the ugliness and everything.
  This code is modified for illustrative purposes.

  What this code does is basically this:

  - Process 3 sequential function calls

    - these calls turns out to consist of:

      - an ajax Call
      - setting div #progress_1 TEXT with ajaxCall response
      - on progress of setting text into a #progress_1 div make DIV green.
 */
```

P.S. When I load page and open a console in Chrome later, I get a TypeError object that I can inspect and it says "Object has no 'when()' method." That gave me the clue where to start. Before that if console was open in Chrome before I load the page it would just show 'TypeError {}' message. Have to research more on why such vast difference in operation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem :p

Apparently the structure of deferred object was changed internally with 0.9.7 release.
Weird enough **changelog** file shows information on the changes under "0.9.6" section.

When I check the console in 0.9.6 for

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
deferred.promise.__proto__
```

I can see that `when()` function is there. And deferred.promise is not an actual Promise object, but something different?.

However when I check same in version 0.9.7 for

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
deferred.promise.__proto__
```

I get back the Promise object that has `then()` method and 'when()` method no longer exists.

So yea, changelog was misleading or maybe I am losing my mind.

If I go to GitHub q library's repo, and select "Tags" -> "0.9.6" -> "CHANGES.md" file, the topmost portion of file shows "0.9.5" section. So I assume author tried to convey that *these are the changes* **FROM** 0.9.5 **that are in** 0.9.6.

Maybe it makes sense, because **master branch** lists changes under **0.9.7**, so they are again, changes **FROM** 0.9.7 to the next version (*I assume 0.9.8*).

Now I know better to not trust the numbers in a changelog! :p

Thanks everyone who participated!

Comment: Good detective work Plyto. Sounds like the author needs to take a serious look at his documentation.